# Apache mod_rewrite does not work

Tags: mod-rewrite

Im using a J2ee application with spring framework 2.0 on a apache tomcat 5.5. I have used URL mapping to change the extension from .jsp to .htm. I have an URL which looks like this
http://www.800promotion.com/promotion.htm?cid=1344159422528120632840257756098788
I want to change it to
http://www.800promotion.com/1344159422528120632840257756098788
I have referred samples of working on mod_rewrite. However I cant seem to get it working. These are the lines in my .htaccess file.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /promotion.htm?cid=$1 [L]

I have checked with my host and they said mod_rewrite was supported on the server. I do not have access to the httpd.conf file. However I have verified from the support that AllowOverride is set to all. When I hit the URL the page works fine however the URL doesnt get mapped. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ promotion.htm?cid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You need a correct .htaccess directives. Try the following solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) promotion.htm?cid=$1 [L,I,U]
```

Comment: It is still the same. No change has happened. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try something very simple like
`RewriteRule   ^oldstuff\.html$  newstuff.html`
to make sure your mod_rewrite works